# CSS3 attribute filtering on names with special characters

Tags: css, css-selectors

For Chartist line graphs, I'm trying to do conditional coloring of points via CSS. The value that determines the color is the ",0" on the `ct:value` attribute, as follows:

```
<line x1="555" y1="317.2833251953125" x2="555.01" y2="317.2833251953125" class="ct-point" ct:value="63624984960667,0"></line>
```

What attribute selector can we use that styles all line elements such that `ct:value` contains ",0"?

I've attempted the following without success:

```
line[ct\:value~=",0"] {
    //etc
}
```

UPDATE: Modified original code to show tilda (~) instead of caret (^).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting an element by its attribute when it has a colon in its name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34446361/selecting-an-element-by-its-attribute-when-it-has-a-colon-in-its-name) - like yours, that question also involves Chartist XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute matching expression, `val^="attribute"` means the attribute has to *start* with `attribute`, not just contain it. You want `*=` instead for just matching somewhere in the string:

```
line[ct\:value*=",0"] {
   ...
```

Comment: You're right, but I looked at the original code and it was actually using tilda (~) - I'll update my question.  So the problem seems to be with the selector or the escape character.

Comment: Sorry, it's `*=`, not `~=`! The "tilde-equals" method only does either full matches or whitespace-separated matches.